# classList.add() is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I tried to stick the social share bar of my website on scroll according to the tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp).

[image]

Link to my website: https://www.staging5.howtostudycantonese.com/how-to-say-crazy-in-cantonese/

I made some modification to the code, and somehow it doesn't work.  I have tested everything with the inspector and I found out the class of the element of social share bar does not change when I scrolled past it.  I believe `classList.add` is the problem there.  I am not sure why it is not working.

The code I am using:

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.querySelector("div.wp-socializer.wpsr-buttons.wpsr-row-1");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think its `classList.add` that isn't working?  What errors are you getting in your console?

Comment: That is a bad tutorial, please do not use `window.onscroll`. Just use [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: Note that you are not updating the value of `sticky` when the user scrolls...

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the variables before the elements are loaded, that's why they are null.

use onload function to avoid this:

```
var header; 
var sticky;

window.onload = function () {
    header = document.querySelector("div.wp-socializer.wpsr-buttons.wpsr-row-1");
    sticky = header.offsetTop;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to below lines in myFunction

```
var header = document.querySelector("div.wp-socializer.wpsr-buttons.wpsr-row-1");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;
```

like

```
function myFunction() {
var header = document.querySelector("div.wp-socializer.wpsr-buttons.wpsr-row-1");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Comment: Or else just *declare them globally* but *assign them locally* before being used.